# What are MMC extension snap-ins?

Tags: windows, mmc, snap-in

Looking through our MMC snap-in code I can't get one concept. We have a tree of different class items inserted into MMC snap-in root node and only two of them [register themselves as extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa815161(VS.85).aspx). These two classes are nothing special compared to any other classes we use to represent the MMC tree items. Yet only these two register themselves in the registry in the `NodeTypes` key and other classes do not.

The only explanation I have is that we don't need to register them at all - just register the snap-in. However I'm not sure.

What are those extensions snap-ins, how are they used and what exactly do I get after registering some class as an extension snap-in in the registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa815508(VS.85).aspx)?

> Extension snap-ins extend the
>   functionality of other snap-ins, but
>   they are not directly added to a
>   console like stand-alone snap-ins.
>   Extension snap-ins can add context
>   menu items, property pages, toolbar
>   buttons, taskpad tasks, and items to
>   the namespace of the extended snap-in
>   (also called the primary snap-in).
>
> Primary snap-ins can themselves extend
>   the functionality of other snap-ins.
>   That is, the same snap-in code base
>   can create a primary snap-in instance
>   and an extension snap-in instance.
>
> An extension snap-in is loaded only
>   when the snap-in it extends is loaded
>   and the feature it extends is used.
>   For example, when the user displays a
>   context menu in a stand-alone snap-in,
>   MMC builds the context menu, prompts
>   the stand-alone snap-in to add its
>   items, and then prompts the extension
>   snap-in to add its items. After all
>   snap-ins have added their items, MMC
>   displays the context menu and then
>   forwards the menu click to the snap-in
>   that owns the item.
>
> An extension snap-in can extend only
>   the node types that a stand-alone
>   snap-in indicates as being extendable.
>   The extension snap-in declares itself
>   as a subordinate to the extendable
>   node types, and then for each
>   occurrence of those node types in the
>   console, the console automatically
>   adds the related snap-in extensions
>   below it.
>
> It is important to understand that a
>   node type can represent a scope item,
>   a standard list view result item, or a
>   virtual list
>    view result item added by the primary
>   snap-in. Consult the documentation for
>   the primary snap-in to determine what
>   the node type represents and the
>   format of its exported data.

Comment: Yeap, I read that, but I don't get practical implication of this. How does this work? Does this mean that I declare that my snapin extends some other snapin and by MMC magic my snapin starts intercepting some calls to that snapin? How do I determine if I really need this or the strange registration code in our project is just redundant?

Comment: I think probably the extent of my answer was the "did you read this" bit - hope you figure it out though. From the looks of things, an primary snapin is the kind you normally add - it is the kind you "add" to mmc manually, while an extension snapin works automagically by adding new features to other snapins.